# Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) heroku node

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack-dev-server

I deployed my react app on Heroku and using Webpack-dev-server to run. It was working fine.

But it started showing Application Error.After looking the logs, it is showing this error:

Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

I was able to find the problem that it is due Node V8 gc default limit and it also provide the solution i.e,

web: node --optimize_for_size --max_old_space_size=460 --gc_interval=100 server.js

here is link where i found the above solution:

https://blog.heroku.com/node-habits-2016#7-avoid-garbage

It is giving solution using node.But i am using Webpack-dev-server which does not require to create server.js file to run the app and directly build and run the app. Can anybody please give the way how to solve this problem with webpack-dev-server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it wise to run Webpack's dev server (which keeps the generated bundle entirely in memory) on Heroku? I'd say that's meant more for production-ready code (so pre-generated bundles and such).

Comment: @robertklep what do you suggest ?

Comment: Reading [this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/).

Comment: i read the link. But i am still not getting it. Are you suggesting that i should generate the production ready code bundle and then deployed it and not use Webpack-dev-server, then what should i use to run my app?

Comment: The Webpack dev server is really only meant to be used during development, it's not a production-ready server. It's based on Express, and it's relatively simple to create a simple Express server that you _can_ use in production.

Comment: thanks @robertklep. I understand now what you are saying.

Comment: hey, do you have a solution to this issue?